# How to check xml node names using <xsl:if>

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having an xml file that goes like this.

```
<RootTag>
    <Form>
        <Section>
             <Annex>
                <Group>
                        <Label value = "Name"></Label>
                        <Text Value = "Enter Name"></Text>
                </Group>
                <Group>
                        <Label value = "Gender"></Label>
                       <Radio Value = "Male||Female"></Text>
                </Group>
            </Annex>
        </Section>
    </Form>
</RootTag>
```

Now in my xsl, I have to check if the tag is `<Text>` or `<Radio>` and generate `<input>` tag based on that result.

Is there any whay I can do it using `<xsl:if>`? Like `<xsl:if test = 'node = <Text>'>`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="name() = 'Form'">
```

However, there are other approaches which may be better:

One is to use a template for this item; the XSLT engine will automatically perform the test, if you want to look at it that way.

```
<xsl:template match="Form">
```

Another is to use the `self::` axis

```
<xsl:for-each select="self::Form">
```